# Why is this Coffeescript invalid?

Tags: coffeescript

I'm playing around with Coffeescript, trying to convert a JavaScript file to Coffeescript. This is valid JavaScript:

```
element(by.model('query.address')).sendKeys('947');
```

This is invalid Coffeescript:

```
element(by.model('query.address')).sendKeys('947')
```

What is invalid about the Coffeescript? Coffeelint says "unexpected BY".

Comment: `unexpected X` means you should be googling about `X` and language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CoffeeScript uses the `by` keyword to let you use a specific step when looping through a range.

From the documentation:

> To step through a range comprehension in fixed-size chunks, use **by**, for example:

```
evens = (x for x in [0..10] by 2)
```

Since JavaScript doesn't use `by` it's valid. For CoffeeScript, try renaming the `by` to something else.

In response to the comment, since Protractor provides its own `by` global variable, one idea is to alias it via CoffeeScript's embedded JavaScript syntax (code surrounded by back-ticks), then continue using CoffeeScript and the alias throughout your code.

You'll need to test this type of code:

```
ptorBy = `by`
element(ptorBy.model('query.address')).sendKeys('947')
```

Where `ptor` is just my short-hand for "Protractor." This translates to the following JavaScript:

```
var ptorBy;
ptorBy = by;
element(ptorBy.model('query.address')).sendKeys('947');
```

Comment: That's a bummer. The testing library I'm using (Protractor) exposes `by` as a global variable. Does that make it incompatible with Coffeescript?

Comment: @BenHarold you might be able to alias it and get it to work. I've edited my response to show this.

Comment: @BenHarold You could try referencing it as `window.by` or `@by` if you're in the right scope.